# local options for floatrow

Tags: floatrow

I am using `floatrow` and have a global setup with `\floatsetup`. However I have one `subfloatrow` in my document which requires different settings. How do I locally adjust the `\floatsetup`/options for one `float`?

Comment: You can use `\floatsetup` inside the floating object itself. The floating object a group and so the setting are local too.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Car to make this an awnser so i can accept this, or should I just delete the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\floatsetup` allows the user to specify some options. This specification is always local.

If you do the setup in your preamble the setup is done for the whole document.

To change the setup for a single subfloat you can use `\floatsetup` inside a group. The floating objects are always a group so you can change `\floatsetup` inside the object without any effects to other objects.

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup{....}

.....

\begin{figure}
\floatsetup{...}% all these settings are local to this floating object
\subfloatrow

\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the [above answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122598/39767) doesn't work (it didn't work for me), try placing `\floatsetup{}` outside the environment, but enclosed in a group. Example:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
…

{ % or \begingroup
\floatsetup{font=tt}
\begin{table}

\caption{A caption}
\label{label1}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
} % or \endgroup
```