# Change font of single floatrow object

Tags: floatrow

I'm using `floatrow` and want to change the the font of a single float object. It says [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122596/local-options-for-floatrow) that this should be possible by placing `\fleatsetup{}` inside the float object. This doesn't work for me.

My setup:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
…
\begin{table}
\floatsetup{font=tt}
\caption{A caption}
\label{label1}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would expect the font to be changed to monospaced, but nothing happens.

Comment: it works if you place `\floatsetup{font=tt}` outside the `table` environment and enclose everything in a group.

Comment: thx, that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by dcmst, `\floatsetup{font=tt}` needs to be placed outside the environment, but inside a group. The above example would have to look like this:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
…

{ % or \begingroup
\floatsetup{font=tt}
\begin{table}

\caption{A caption}
\label{label1}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
} % or \endgroup
```